# Avast detected slow program

Tags: windows-7, performance, anti-virus, avast

Recently my computer has just gotten so slow. I downloaded CCleaner and along with it came Avast. The former I ran and got rid of a bunch of junk slowing down my computer, but it was still slow so I decided to use Avast. I ran the Cleanup Premium test and under Programs slowing down your PC - this is what it detected:

[image: Avast]

[image: Programs slowing down your PC]

I checked online and it seems that "Digital TV Tuner device registration application" belongs to Windows Media Center and it enables you to  watch cable TV.

According to Avast, it's slowing down my laptop by 72%. I tried to uninstall Windows Media Center via the control panel but I could not find it there. Is there any way to safely remove it or fix this issue?

Comment: Do not pay too much attention to a feature intended *only* to sell you a product.

Comment: What anti virus would you suggest I use? Or how can I keep my computer running fast and safe?

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here and so are too broad and "primarily opinion based" questions.

Comment: You are telling me I can't ask for help to fix my computer on a site that was made to help people fix with problems on their computers?

Comment: I'm saying you should take th tour: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @user772515 There are other sites that allow those kinds of questions, like https://www.slant.co/topics/3878/~antivirus-software-for-windows

Answer (score 4):

just go to add/remove programs, select turn windows features on or off and scroll to media features then un-tick media center (unless you use it) as it is part of media center :)

Comment: Does this have any side effects?

Answer (score 3):

If your computer is legitimately slow and you actually want to fix it, learn how to diagnose problems based on the actual indicators of performance issues, which you can find built into the system.

Windows' Resource Monitor tool is something that every user should be familiar with. To start it, first open Task Manager (Ctrl+Alt+Delete -> Task Manager). In Task Manager, click on the Performance tab, then click "Open Resource Monitor" at the bottom.

The three tabs you'll mainly be concerned with are:

- CPU,
- Memory,
- Disk.

Basically you want to look for processes that are consuming huge amounts of one or more of these resources. These are the processes that are slowing down your computer.

If no particular process jumps out at you as consuming huge resources by itself, you might just have too many programs installed at once for the resources you have available on your system. If this is the case, you'll need to either uninstall some programs and live without them, or close them (including any background processes they might keep running when you close the window), or upgrade your system with better components, or as a last resort, get a new system.

Don't rely on shiny shrinkwrapped programs to tell you what's slow based on some heuristic. Most often they are not very accurate. Instead, dig down into the raw data and diagnose it yourself. Then figure out what program the offending process is related to, and either temporarily kill, uninstall, or delete the offending program.

For your reference: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-use-resource-monitor-windows-7